# When I'm running jar as a service with the help of nssm the JOptionPane.showOptionDialog() is not showing up

Tags: java, windows-services, joptionpane, nssm

My program has the piece of code which pop-up the window dialogue box notifying the user about the ongoing process for this I'm using **JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()**

But when I'm starting the program as a service instead of running a jar file, I'm not able to see the pop-up window

I'm using **nssm** to create the service from jar/bat file

The following code is responsible to show the pop-up window

```
private void showWindow(String msg) {

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(msg);
        textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 18));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setSize(new Dimension(400, 10));

        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, textArea,
                "Application",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                null, null, null);

    }
```

I want to understand, Does service allow the program to show a window like this on a foreground?

Comment: Have you checked in any way that your service actually runs? have it create a log file and see if, when running your service, that actually gets created

Comment: I believe services are headless and cannot create any GUI components.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, I did generate logs, The service is running fine in the background